# What do the numbers written on this IC mean?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32

I was delivered an STM32F407VGT6 with E3. I have used an STM32F407VGT6 E4 in my earlier projects.

Due to this I have errors at runtime (timing). Can you help me understand the meaning of the numbers written on the i
IC?

[image]

Specifically the 07 at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're receiving parts marked with an 'E' revision code (rather than an 'R') then according to the [Datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf) those are "Engineering Samples":
[image]

Engineering Samples are not typically made available to the general public or offered for sale through *reputable* distributors.
As ST notes in the datasheet, these sample parts are not "qualified" and "not yet ready to be used in production".
They almost certainly *do* have bugs in them - and those bugs are not documented anywhere which *you have access to* (unlike the bugs in the officially released parts which are documented in the [Errata sheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/errata_sheet/es0182-stm32f405407xx-and-stm32f415417xx-device-limitations-stmicroelectronics.pdf)), so you'll never know for sure whether your device is going to work properly or if it's going to work at all in the longer term.

So if you don't want to run into these kind of issues, stop buying your parts through fleebay, pali-express, etc. and use the reputable official distributors instead, like Newark, Digikey, Mouser, Arrow, etc.

Comment: I don't have any type of revision codes mentioned!!! As u can see from above pic

Answer (score 4):

If you look into the datasheet and try to use the find command for the specific characters, you will see this:

- product ID
- revision code
- Manufacturing year/month

[image]
<sub>Image source datasheet: [datasheet link](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf)</sub>

Comment: Any idea what 07 bottom right mean?

Comment: Absolutely no idea..